# Calculate the difference between two dates in bash where date format is 08/Sep/2022

Tags: bash, shell, date, awk, sed

I have two dates in below format. I have to calculate the difference between two days in Seconds.

```
currentDateTime="08/Sep/2022:05:26:13"

logDateTime="07/Sep/2022:04:58:30"

diff=$(echo "$(($(date -d "$currentDateTime" +'%s')-$(date -d "$currentDateTime" +'%s')))")

echo $diff
```

The output is empty. Can someone help me here

Comment: I get from your `date` command (with `LANG` set to `en_GB.utf8`) the error message _invalid date_. What is your `LANG` setting?

Comment: @user1934428 : i got it to worrk once you change `Sep` to `9` and change `2022:` to `2022 `

Comment: Are you by any chance doing this in a loop reading dates from somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the date in this format:
`08 Sep 2022 05:26:13`
You can perform something like this:

```
currentDate=$(echo $currentDateTime | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | awk -F'/' '{print $1,$2,$3}')
currentTime=$(echo $currentDateTime | awk -F':' '{printf "%s:%s:%s",$2,$3,$4}')

logDate=$(echo $logDateTime | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | awk -F'/' '{print $1,$2,$3}')
logTime=$(echo $logDateTime | awk -F':' '{printf "%s:%s:%s",$2,$3,$4}')

diff=$(echo "$(($(date -d "$(echo "$currentDate $currentTime")" +'%s')-$(date -d "$(echo "$logDate $logTime")" +'%s')))")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ logDateTime="07/Sep/2022:04:58:30"
$ logDateTime="${logDateTime//:*/ ${logDateTime#*:}}"
$ currentDateTime="08/Sep/2022:05:26:13"
$ currentDateTime="${currentDateTime//:*/ ${currentDateTime#*:}}"
$ let diff=($(date +%s -d "${currentDateTime//// }")-$(date +%s -d "${logDateTime//// }"))
$ echo $diff
88063
```